# Wicket Modal Window, any way to close it if i click outside of the modal window?

Tags: modal-dialog, window, wicket

As the title says, i am working using wicket 6 and it would be very useful if the modal window was to close when i clicked outside of the bounds of the modal window, anyone have any idea on how i might go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding this JS to your page:

```
$(function() {
    $('.wicket-mask-dark').click(function() {
        $('.w_close').click();
    });
});
```

Comment: no joy i am afraid nothing happens, even tried to add an alert to see if it recognized the click on class wicket-mask-dark

Comment: Just tested it at http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/ajax/modal-window. Open Dev Tools > Console, paste the code from above, click anywhere on the mask.